# Android quiz with arrays not working

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am currently doing a multiple choice quiz of 10 questions using arrays and radio buttons. the quiz itself runs on the emulator through genymotion using the android studio but the answer and questions and correct answers fields are all showing as blank. I have created the quiz using the click on listener but it does not seem to be clicking past to the next screen. i have tried altering all sorts of code and can't seem to find anything that reads arrays into the radio buttons a,b,c and d. can anyone solve this? i have attached the code, i think the code should increment correctly though i have to add 8 more questions yet.

```
package com.quiz.newquiz.app;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private int currentQuestion;
    private String [] questions;
    private String [] answers;

    private Button answerButton;
    private Button questionButton;
    private TextView questionView;
    private TextView answerView;
    private EditText answerText;

    @Override

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialise();
    }

    public void initialise()
    {
        questions = new String[]{"What is the capital of Egypt?","What class are you in?"};
        answers = new String[] {"Cairo","Class B"};
        answerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.AnswerButton);
        questionButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.QuestionButton);
        questionView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.QuestionTextView);
        answerView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.AnswerTextView);
        answerText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.AnswerText);
        answerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override

        public void onClick(View view){
                checkAnswer();
            }
        });

        questionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showQuestion();


            }
        });
    }
    public void showQuestion()
    { currentQuestion=0;
            if(currentQuestion<10)
                currentQuestion++;
        questionView.setText(questions[currentQuestion]);
        answerView.setText("");
        answerText.setText("");
    }

    public boolean isCorrect(String answer)
    {
        return (answer.equalsIgnoreCase(answers[currentQuestion]));
    }
    public void checkAnswer()
    {
        String answer = answerText.getText().toString();
        if(isCorrect(answer))
            answerView.setText("You are correct!");
        else
            answerView.setText("Sorry, the correct answer is " + answers[currentQuestion]);


    }
}
```

Comment: does the string need to be written like this? private  String [] answerA=new String[10]; rather than private String [] = answerA

Answer (score 1):

See this line in your code:

```
 public void showQuestion()
{ currentQuestion=0;
        if(currentQuestion<10)
            currentQuestion++;
    questionView.setText(questions[currentQuestion]);
    answerView.setText("");
    answerText.setText("");
}
```

Your currentQuestion variable is always assigned a value of 0 and is checked. increment current question in your click listener.

```
questionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        currentQuestion++;               
        showQuestion();

        }
    });
```

Comment: increment it in this one? questionView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                RadioGroup grp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
                RadioButton id = (RadioButton) findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                showQuestion();

Comment: or this one?  answerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()



        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                currentQuestion++;
                checkAnswer();

            }
        });

Comment: if i add } after set text, everything below turns red like an error. is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: thank you, i will have a look at it now-unfortunately android studio has just frozen on me again!

Comment: android studio is great but its still in beta so if you are not comfortable use ecllipse

Comment: thank you i will try that. i am also using another quiz with questions stored in sqlite. i have changed the questions on android studio and answers to ones that i want but when i run the app, the question and answer buttons still come up with the default suggestions. i found the template at developer feed and have checked the source folder and there is no sign of a database or sql in the folders. have you any ideas on how to remove? i can post a separate question if necessary.